# how to do jquery tab custmization

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using jquery tab in asp.net MVC application. I need to customise the tab with below,

1. need to change the background color of tabs, this is done by below CSS,

   ```
   .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-nav a
   {
       background-color: #EBF1DE;
   }
   ```
2. Now when a tab is selected, the background color should be red, but below code not   works, always the color is "#EBF1DE", but other attribute (like font weight:bolder works),

   ```
   .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-header .ui-state- active
   {
       font-weight: bolder;
   }
   ```
3. Also how to get rid of below red highlited backgroud,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IMO the best way is to not use the default theme, and put up your own, you can add your own selectors and style them, or use [themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) ?

If you are not a designer I think themeroller would be the best bet for you.